# Proper way of avoiding deprecated code warning

Tags: raku

I use `CompUnit::PrecompilationStore::File` in a module, which passes all my tests under Rakudo v2022.02 (on my local machine I have not yet upgraded Raku).

Under Rakudo v2022.06, `zef test .` in the module directory causes a deprecation error (see details below) (reported to me in an issue on the module's github repo).

Simply replacing `File` with `FileSystem` in the relevant line locally now causes errors under Rakudo v2022.02.

What is the best way of handling this situation in the Module?

Details of error

```
Pod::From::Cache] Saw 1 occurrence of deprecated code.
[Pod::From::Cache] ================================================================================
[Pod::From::Cache] Use of the 'CompUnit::PrecompilationStore::File' class seen at:
[Pod::From::Cache]   /Users/coke/sandbox/raku-pod-from-cache/lib/Pod/From/Cache.rakumod (Pod::From::Cache), line 46
[Pod::From::Cache] Please use the 'CompUnit::PrecompilationStore::FileSystem' class instead.
[Pod::From::Cache] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pod::From::Cache] Please contact the author to have these occurrences of deprecated code
[Pod::From::Cache] adapted, so that this message will disappear!
```

Answer (score 3):

Run your code with the [RAKUDO_NO_DEPRECATIONS](https://docs.raku.org/programs/03-environment-variables#index-entry-RAKUDO__NO__DEPRECATIONS) environment variable set.

```
%*ENV<RAKUDO_NO_DEPRECATIONS> = 1;
CompUnit::PrecompilationStore::File.new(:prefix(".".IO));
```

Comment: how to have code specific for a compiler version, eg, rakudo >= v2022.06 ?

Comment: `Compiler.new.version >= v2022.06`

Comment: As I understand it, this doesn't fix the issue, but masks it, so that when a rakudo is released that removes the deprecated item, the code will start breaking.

I think you need to resolve the issue by updating the code otherwise this is just pushing the problem down the road.